# Concrete5 - Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, concrete5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone come across this php error before, Warning: imagejpeg()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312406/has-anyone-come-across-this-php-error-before-warning-imagejpeg)

I'm migrating a Concrete5 site to the live server and keep getting this error on some pages. Mainly the pages using the Dojo page filter addon/block, but not always.

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/SITENAME/public_html/files/cache/052f225905c1618003df0c5088aec7a9.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /home/SITENAME/public_html/concrete/helpers/image.php on line 172

I've tried changing the permissions on the files folder to 755 and applied to enclosed folders but still no luck?

Any ideas?

I'm running 5.4.2.2 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions may not have gotten applied to existing files -- talk to your web host's tech support (or peruse their knowledge base) for info on how to set all files in that directory to 644 (recursively -- so it hits every file in every sub-folder too).