# Has anyone come across this php error before, Warning: imagejpeg()?

Tags: permissions, cpanel, php, concrete5

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/SITENAME/public_html/files/cache/052f225905c1618003df0c5088aec7a9.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /home/SITENAME/public_html/concrete/helpers/image.php on line 172
```

I emptied the cache directory and still no luck, and if I change the permissions on the cache folder then I get another error and I can't use the site at all:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/concrete/libraries/3rdparty/Zend/Cache.php on line 133

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/owen/php') in /home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/concrete/libraries/3rdparty/Zend/Cache.php on line 133
```

I don't get it? I've never had this problem before.

Comment: The file doesn't exist??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference the problem was the PHP handler. It has been changed to CGI mode (as opposed to DSO) and they turned suEXEC ‘off’ - might be useful for someone down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions problem to me, but we can't tell from this end.

If you can FTP (or CD) into that /home/SITENAME/public_html/files/

and see if 'files' is owned by, and has the same permissions as public_html

Then see what permissions they NEED to have for your hosting setup.

Comment: Public html has the same owner but a different group. The permissions for public html are 750, I've got 777 on the files folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that directory exists.
2. Check if web server daemon, most of the time - www-data, has write permissions to that particular directory.

Comment: The directory exists and the files folder has 777 world writable permissions. Still no luck. The public_html folder is owned by my account as in my cpanel account and so are the folders beneath it. 

How can I check if web server daemon has write permissions? I can't change the user to www-data, I've tried that.

Comment: The, the best option will be contacting Your hosting provider for support. There is obviously something wrong with the host itself.

Comment: Thanks Matiss, it was getting really urgent and I had run out of ideas. I've spoken to the host provider this morning and they seem to think that the Concrete5 cms prefers a different php config setup. I'll add more when I know the full answer.